# The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: java, mysql

These are the data i am going to pass in,

3/8/2010 6:37:16 AM

while i have column declared as datetime type in db table.
Its fishy that it did not worked as i have another java class doing similar query but succeeded passing into db.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `parse / convert` "string" value (using `SimpleDateFormat` or joda-time API) to `date-time` before you go for insert.